# How to create a custom filter on Django Admin Model?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to create a custom filter using some selectors on a model called Foo.

I have simple Admin page for this model created using:

```py
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ["created_at", CustomFilter]
```

I want to create a CustomFilter where the user can select to run this custom query as a filter like this:
[image]

I have something like this but it requires a parameter_name which restricts it to a single attribute to be filtered in the Foo model. Is there a way around this?:

```py
class CustomListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    def lookups(
        self,
        request,
        model_admin,
    ) -> List[Tuple[str, str]]:
        return [
            ("getCustomFilter", ("True")),
        ]

    def queryset(self, request: Any, queryset: QuerySet) -> Optional[QuerySet]:
        if self.value() == "getCustomFilter":
            return Foo.selector.order_by_something().distinct_on_something()
        
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

`parameter_name` it's not important for your scenario so you can set this with fake value

so

```
class CustomListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title='By Use Custom Filter'
    parameter_name='apply'

    def lookups(
        self,
        request,
        model_admin,
    ) -> List[Tuple[str, str]]:
        return [
            ("getCustomFilter", ("True")),
        ]

    def queryset(self, request: Any, queryset: QuerySet) -> Optional[QuerySet]:
        if self.value():
            return Foo.objects.filter(yourFilter)
```